# Execution plan of a query

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get the execution plan of a statement in postgresql. This statement is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE example LOCATION 'C:\example\';
```

The code I have tried is as follows:

```
EXPLAIN CREATE TABLESPACE example LOCATION 'C:\example\';
```

However, Postgresql indicates syntax error at or near "TABLESPACE".

Any idea?

Thnak you in advance

Comment: There is no execution plan for that. Why do you think you need it? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, I simply want to analyze the execution plan that PostgreSQL uses to solve such a query. But if it really does not leave as you say should not leave a notification indicating what you say and I get syntax error? I have checked references and I think my query is ok but I do not get the result.

Comment: It's not a "query" it's a utility statement that essentially only creates a directory. There is not much of a plan to be shown.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes I finally say it in the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html), you can see the execution plan only for `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `VALUES`, `EXECUTE`, `DECLARE`, `CREATE TABLE AS`, or `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS` statements.

So it is not impossible for `CREATE TABLESPACE` statements.

Comment: I see... Okay Thank you then @Oleskii Tambovtsev